# JFace idle processing in event loop

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have implemented idle processing (e.g. updating menu items, buttons, etc) in an event loop using SWT like this:

```
   shell.open();
   while (!shell.isDisposed())
   {
       if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          if (doIdle()) display.sleep();
   }
   shell.dispose();
```

Now that I'm trying to learn JFace, I don't see a good way to do this.  The ApplicationWindow open method calls Window.runEventLoop which is private.   This tells me that I'm probably misunderstanding something simple.

Anybody know how to implement something like this without rewriting code?

Comment: Can you please explain to me why you chose this approach and don't just use a `Thread` in the background?

Comment: Probably my inexperience with Java threading.  This method is convenient because the things I'm updating just changed -- such as after selecting a menu item.